# Field with four elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

If $F=\{0,1,a,b\}$ is a field (where the four elements are distinct), then:

1. What is the characteristic of $F$?
2. Write $b$ in terms of the other elements.
3. What are the multiplication and addition tableau of these operations?

Comment: Reasonable questions... and you're getting reasonable responses. But, for the style of this site, in the future, you should show your own thoughts, in addition to just posing questions. Especially if/when you pose the question in a way that it looks like a homework question, etc. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The addition: $\;a+b=0\implies a=-b=b\;$ , since $\;\text{char}\, F=2\;$ . It also can't be $\;a+b=a\;,\;\;a+b=b\;$ , else $\;b=0\;$ or $\;a=0\;$ . Thus it must be $$\;a+b=1\implies b=1-a=1+a\;$$

Generalize the above and get the addition table.

As for multiplication $\;ab\neq 0,a,b\;$ , else $\;a=0\;$ or $\;b=0\;$ , or $\;a,b=1\;$ and none of this is true, thus it must be $\;ab=1\iff b=a^{-1}\;$ . Generalize now for the table.

Answer (score 5):

A field has characteristic a prime number $p$ or $0$, (consider the homomorphism $\mathbf Z\rightarrow F, \enspace n\mapsto n\cdot 1$.

Any finite field $\mathbf F_{p^n}$ is an extension of degree $n$ of the prime field $\mathbf F_p$ and it is a simple extension of $\mathbf F_p$  generated  by a root of any irreducible polynomial of degree $n$ in $\mathbf F_p[x]$. In the present case the only irreducible polynomial of degree $2$ is $x^2+x+1$. Let $\omega$ be one of its roots; the other root is its inverse, $\omega+1$.

Here is its multiplication table:
$$\begin{array}{c|cccc}
&0&1 &\omega&\omega+1\\\hline
0&0&0&0&0\\\hline
1&0&1 &\omega&\omega+1\\\hline
\omega&0&\omega&\omega+1&1\\\hline
\omega+1&0&\omega+1&1&\omega
\end{array}$$

Comment: The other answers give good ways to persuade yourself of the result, but this one is the right way to remember it once you know it.

Answer (score 1):

For (1), suppose that the characteristic is $4$. Then, $1 + 1 \neq 0$, but $$(1 + 1)(1 + 1) = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 0,$$ so $1 + 1$ is a zero divisor, a contradiction, and hence the characteristic is $2$. One can use this sort of argument to show that the characteristic of any integral domain is either $0$ or prime.

Since the characteristic is $2$, for every $x \in F$ we have $x + x = (1 + 1)x = 0$, so every element has order $\leq 2$ under $+$, and this determines up to isomorphism the underlying group $(F, +)$, which in particular lets you solve (2) and the first part of (3). The second part of (3) follows quickly from this.